# jquery cleaning up my multiple ifs

Tags: jquery

I have a page with several divs and each div has a button to hide or display certain things within that div by adding different classes on click. I've currently got it working, but I'm using multiple if statements to check which button was clicked. My current code looks like this:

```
$(".classofallbuttons").click(function () {
id = this.id;
if (id === 'btnid5'){
     $("#divtoggle5").toggleClass("firstclass");
     $("#divtoggle5").toggleClass("secondclass");
}
if (id === 'btnid6'){
     $("#divtoggle6").toggleClass("firstclass");
     $("#divtoggle6").toggleClass("secondclass");
}
```

And although it works, there are 10 or more divs, and it seems like I should be able to do something more streamlined since everything is the same except for the IDs of the buttons and the divs. But I'm new at this so I'm not sure what would be the best way?

Comment: is the button inside respective `<div>`..? If you post the HTML markup, you might get an even better solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass) method accepts more than one classes to be toggled.

You can do it like this:

```
$(".classofallbuttons").click(function() {
  var n = this.id.split("btnid")[1];
  $("#divtoggle" + n).toggleClass("firstclass secondclass");
});
```

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I hoped for, thank you! Only one question, if some of the IDs are in double or triple digits, this wouldn't work right? Unless I changed the IDs to be (for instance) 001, 021 etc and changed the var to grab the last 3 characters instead? edit: sorry I see you updated while I was typing. Awesome, thank you both!

Comment: @TJ thanks for that - that may be helpful in the future. In this case though the button is outside the div that the class is being changed on.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract index from current button id.

```
$('.classofallbuttons').click(function(){
    var id = +/(\d+)/.exec(this.id)[1];
    $('#divtoggle' + id).toggleClass('firstclass secondclass')
});
```